# Is it possible to prevent LINQ from using variables in queries and instead use string literals?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a LINQ query that has lots of variables and the generated SQL looks something like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT col1, col2
FROM MyTable [t3]
WHERE 
  (([t3].[col1] = @p0) AND ([t3].[col2] = @p1))
  OR (([t3].[col1] = @p2) AND ([t3].[col2] = @p3))
  ...
N'@p0 varchar(32),@p1 varchar(32),@p2 varchar(32),@p3 varchar(32),...
,@p0='0',@p1='1',@p2='2',@p3='3',...
```

This works fine as long as there are not too many variables, say 150 or less.  But when there are too many variables, the query slows down significantly.

If I have the same query, except that there are no variables, like:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM MyTable [t3]
WHERE
  (([t3].[col1] = '0') AND ([t3].[col2] = '1'))
  OR (([t3].[col1] = '2') AND ([t3].[col2] = '3'))
  ...
```

Then the query works fine, even when there are many OR conditions.

While I believe this is really an issue with SQL Server behaving poorly when there are too many variables, I am wondering if I can workaround this issue in LINQ by not having the generated SQL contain references to variables, but instead use string literals.

I realize that I can workaround this issue by not using LINQ, and instead constructing the SQL myself, but hoping to have a LINQ solution.

Also, while this question is about LINQ, if there's a solution to speeding up the query which involves SQL Server, I'd be interested in that as well.  I should add that I am seeing this issue with SQL Server 2005.

Thanks for your help,
Eric

Comment: While not an answer to my question, I now understand why the different queries produce such different performance.  In the case where there are lots of parameters, the execution plan (unfortunately) uses a clustered index scan; whereas when string literals are used instead of parameters, the execution plan (fortunately) uses an index seek.  That is what is causing the drastic difference in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. In fact one of the features of Linq is that it prevents users from [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

You may have better performance if you load your query parameters into a table, and then run your query as a join against the table.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very broad. It is likely that LINQ itself has nothing to do with your query performance.

If you have a lot of `OR` in the query this is what makes SQL query optimizer get confused on what index to use if any.

In my opinion you need to focus on the SQL query optimization first, add appropriate indexes. When SQL query is optimized you will not have issues with LINQ.

[EDIT]

If you use string literals, you might end up with worse performance, as SQL query optimizer will not be able to reuse query plans. Every query will trigger new query plan generation.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and, in fact, that's what I initially focused on.  It was only after some investigation that I realized the issue was specific to having the variables in the query.  I don't believe this is an issue with LINQ (I think it's an issue with SQL Server), but I am wondering if LINQ can workaround the issue.

Comment: @Eric - If you can't make a SQL query that performs well, LINQ can't either. I don't believe that using literals will fix this issue. I think it will aggravate it.

Comment: Alex, the point is that I can make a SQL query that performs well, as long as the query doesn't have too many variables.  The 2nd query in my question (the one without variables) performs well with many OR conditions.  For example, a query with variables takes 8 minutes, but that same query without bind variables takes only a few seconds.

Comment: @Eric - I see. I'm pretty sure that query optimizes query specifically for those literals that you provided.

Comment: @Eric - Linq always generates parameters. The workaround could be in creating a stored procedure, that has all those parameters, but it builds query dynamically using literals. I would never do something like this, but this would be exactly the solution you are asking about, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, parameters is not the problem. Many ORs in the where clause can confuse SQL Server, whether the query is parameterized or not.

One workaround is to change your query to UNION query with one UNION for each OR.

E.g.:

```
select ... from MyTable as t0 where t0.col1 = 0 and t0.col2 = 1
  union all
select ... from MyTable as t1 where t1.col1 = 2 and t0.col2 = 3
```

You can easily build up a query similar to that in a loop using the LINQ .Union method:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> IDPairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>> { new Tuple<int, int>(0,1), new Tuple<int, int>(2,3) }

IQueryable<MyTable> query = null;
foreach (Tuple<int, int> IDs in IDPairs)
{
  if (query == null)
  {
    query = dc.MyTable.Where(w => w.Col1 == IDs.Item1 && w.Col2 == IDs.Item2);
  }
  else
  {
    query = query.Union(dc.MyTable.Where(w => w.Col1 == IDs.Item1 && w.Col2 == IDs.Item2));
  }
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: From all of my research, parameters are the problem.  As I mentioned above, if I have 2 queries which do the same thing, one with parameters (2000) and one with no parameters, the query goes from 8 minutes to a few seconds.  Before I realized this, I also tried the UNION idea, but since the problem is not caused by the many ORs, it didn't make a difference.  Admittedly, I am surprised that others are very surprised it's a parameter issue, and surprised that too many parameters causing issues in SQL Server is not a more well known issue (I have yet to find anyone else with this issue).

Comment: I don't think the parameters are the _cause_ of the problem. They may _mask_ the problem by making SQL Server reuse a bad execution plan. Can you reproduce the same behavior repeatedly if you run _dbcc freeproccache_ in between attempts?

Comment: I now understand what is happening (see my comment in the question).  Briefly, the execution plan is switching from using an index seek to a clustered index scan once a certain number of parameters are exceeded. And the clustered index scan (not surprisingly) has considerably worse performance.

Comment: Also, I am able to reproduce the same behavior repeatedly if I run dbcc freeproccache in between attempts.  If I were to guess, I'd say SQL Server is doing something like, "Oh, there's lots of OR conditions and I don't know what the value of those parameters are, but since there's so many, it's probably better to use an index scan rather than an index seek."

Comment: Ok, so your best recourse is to go for the union approach described above. JMHO.